# Google Chat Webhook message can be deleted by anyone. How to prevent it?

Tags: webhooks, google-chat

I created a webhook for Google Chat, which informs about the relevant stuff. However, at the same time I discovered that this message can be deleted by anyone - including people outside the organization. There is no option for editing at least.

When someone clicks the Delete button (no matter who), it lefts a nothe that message has been deleted **by its author**.

I want to add that webhook is added to a annoucement space, where only managers can post.

Is there anyone, who knows why it is working like that and if there is any way to prevent webhook message from deletion by any random user?